# How to enable/disable the left/right side menu ionic

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have both left and right side menus in my page. My app has English/Arabic translation. When in english language the panel should be from left side and for the arabic the panel should be from right side.

So I am planning to have both the menus in my page and enable/disable the left/right panel menu according to the language.

My menu page will look something similar to below:

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <!-- Left menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="left" is-enabled={{enableLeftMenu}}>
  </ion-side-menu>

  <ion-side-menu-content>
  <!-- Main content, usually <ion-nav-view> -->
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <!-- Right menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="right" is-enabled={{!enableLeftMenu}}>
  </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

So I am trying to play with `"is-enabled"` attribute.
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenu/

But the problem is when I change the value of `is-enabled` attribute from controller, it is not getting affected in the view.

Comment: cant we achieve your requiremnt with show/hide??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to inject `$ionicSideMenuDelegate` into your controller and then use the `toggleLeft()` or `toggleRight()` function on it, depending on which menu you want to toggle.

As mentioned in another answer, you can use `drag-content="true"` to enable/disable dragging, or use `canDragContent(false)` in your JS to enable/disable it :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Though this answer helps, I need to disable the drag so i can use this to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "disable the drag"?

Comment: I can swipe the page to see the panel menu other than clicking on the menu icon. So if swiping is enabled then the user can see both the panels.

Answer (score 0):

I found this example on Codepen that maybe can be of help for you:

http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/kKtFz

*Example provided*

```
<ion-side-menu side="left">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
    <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <ul class="list">
      <!-- Note each link has the 'menu-close' attribute so the menu auto closes when clicking on one of these links -->
      <a href="#/event/check-in" class="item" menu-close>Check-in</a>
      <a href="#/event/attendees" class="item" menu-close>Attendees</a>
    </ul>
  </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>

<ion-side-menu side="right">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
    <h1 class="title">Right Menu</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
   Some content
  </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable dragging, you can either add an attribute to the directive or use the $ionicSideMenuDelegate in your controller:

Check option a) here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenuContent/

```
<ion-side-menu-content
  drag-content="false">
</ion-side-menu-content>
```

.. or option b) here:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSideMenuDelegate/

```
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
```